# What to do with driver which is "activated but not currently in use"?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

1. Ubuntu 12.04, graphics card: GeForce-4 MX 420,
2. From Nvidia website, downloaded NVIDIA-Linux-x86-96.43.18.pkg1.run
3. Moved it from Downloads folder to "Nvidia folder".
4. I searched for "Additional Drivers".
5. I got a response that Nvidia-(Current) was "activated but not currently in use".
6. What should I do?
   a. Did I download it incorrectly?
   b. Did I move, open or install it incorrectly?
   c. I want to update driver to improve rendering.
   d. I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Moving `NVIDIA-Linux-x86-96.43.18.pkg1.run` to some folder doesn't install it. You have to turn off x server and execute the pkg to install. (many question asked on this site , please search)

`Additional drivers` does the download and installation. (which is already done).

Know which driver in use by executing `lsmod` from terminal. There are two drivers for nvidia. One is open source `nouveau` and other closed source from nvidia (which gets installed if you install from nivida provided pkg ) . Either one of them is allowed and other will be blacklisted.

Answer (score 0):

When you move the downloaded file this doesn't mean that is installed. you have to install it manually

To do that:

First press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + f1 This will open tty1

Now you are using the tty terminal console

log in with your user name and password

Now stop the lightdm(gdm or whatever) using the command

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

Then install the new driver with

```
sudo sh /path-to-the-driver
```

- if something goes wrong close the installer and reboot then try again
- still same problem the nvidia installer will make a black list in /etc/modprobe.d/
- if this is not generated you have to make such file to black list nouveau
- Run sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf and fill it with this:
  blacklist nouveau
- If the problem is not solve you have to add the string "nomodeset" to your /etc/default/grub, in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=....` line
- then update the grub

  sudo update-grub